# Problema con la instancia de una clase sin constructor de 0 argumentos c#

Tags: c#

Estoy metido en un lío, tengo este codigo:

```
public class Clase
{
  public string Nombre {get; set;}

  public Task<List<NombreClase>>? DetalleClase {get, set;}

  public Clase() //constructor
  {
    DetalleClase = new Task<List<NombreClase>>();
  }  
}
```

Porque lo que necesito es llamarlo en consola de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var clase = New Clase()
  {
    Nombre = "Ana",
    DetalleClase = new Task<List<NombreClase>>
    {
      new NombreClase
      {
        Propiedad1 = '',
        Propiedad2 = ''
      },
      new NombreClase
      {
        Propiedad1 = '',
        Propiedad2 = ''
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Pero no obtengo respuesta favorable porque el compilador de VS me dice que Task<List> no tiene un constructor que tome 0 argumentos.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, apenas estoy empapandome con c#, vengo de Vb.NET

Comment: ¿Por qué un `Task` ? ¿Seguro que eso es lo que necesitas?

Comment: @fredyfx Se que es un poco extraño pero por el momento estoy haciendo pruebas en consola con el tipo Tarea (Task) porque lo que voy a crear al final sera un API CRUD que pueda ser consumido en Blazor sin EF con puro ADO NET, entonces si.. si necesito que sea task porque trabajare con procesos asincronos en el Blazor del lado del Servidor

Comment: En ese caso, te sugiero que leas: https://www.dotnetperls.com/constructor Saludos.

Comment: El problema es que si hago la inyección al constructor del tipo Task, cuando haga la instancia en el Program.cs de la consola me va a pedir ese parámetro de entrada (el Task<List<>>) y ademas de eso me marca cuando quiero agregarle un nuevo detalle a esa propiedad en específico me sale que Task<Lis<>> No contiene un constructor que tome 0 argumentos.

Comment: Aquí también hay buen material en español: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/ éxitos con el aprendizaje :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tienes un error conceptual.

Digamos que tienes una lista de esta manera:

```
new List<NombreClase>
    {
      new NombreClase
      {
        Propiedad1 = '',
        Propiedad2 = ''
      },
      //etc
    }
```

Aquí tienes una lista que contiene elementos del tipo "NombreClase", a la cual le asignas elementos en el momento de su instanciación.
Yo lo que veo es que quieres emplear la misma lógica a Task, y tu problema es que no es lo mismo.

Un objeto del tipo Task hace referencia a un delegado el cual a su vez referencia a un evento o función. Es decir, Task es "algo" que sucede no "algo" que contiene. Además cuando haces `Task<algo>`, ese "algo" es el retorno de la tarea, no lo que contiene la tarea.

Si quieres envolver tu lista, para que esta se ejecute de manera asincrona (ya que entiendo que el código que publicas es un mero ejemplo de algo más grande que estas realizando), puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Clase clase = new Clase();
        await clase.Add(new NombreClase());
        await clase.Add(new NombreClase());

        var lista = await clase.GetList();
    }
}

public class Clase
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    private List<NombreClase> DetalleClase { get; set; }
    public Clase() //constructor
    {
        DetalleClase = new List<NombreClase>();
    }

    public async Task Add(NombreClase clase)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            DetalleClase.Add(clase);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    }

    public async Task<List<NombreClase>> GetList()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return DetalleClase;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Woooow ya, ya entendí, y tienes toda la razón, mi error era conceptual y me lo explicaste de una manera concisa y concreta, muchas gracias amigo Yussef, tu codigo me sirvió a la perfección y ahora que comprendí un poco más como funcionan las tareas ya tengo una idea mas clara para lo que pretendo aplicar. Agradezco mucho la explicación y la propuesta.